# How to access the sub text having no attributes using Watir

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

In following html

```
<p>
<strong>Name:</strong>
12121
</p>
```

How can I access the "12121" text using Watir?

Comment: " <p>
 <strong>Name:</strong>
 12121
 </p>

Comment: Are you using watir-classic (ie just using IE) or watir-webdriver (ie also using Firefox or Chrome)?

Comment: watir-webdriver (ie also using Firefox or Chrome)

Answer (score 3):

To get subtext 12121 use Regular expressions.

gsub performs a search-and-replace operation. It will search for all non-digit characters(/\D/) and replace with the given string.
In this case we are not giving any string to replace.

=browser.p.text.gsub(/\D/, "")

=> "12121"

Answer (score 1):

`browser.p.text` returns `"Name: 12121"` and `browser.p.strong.text` returns `"Name:"`.

```
> browser.p.text
 => "Name: 12121" 

> browser.p.strong.text
 => "Name:"
```

To get `12121` one (or more) of [String](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html) methods could be used, for example [String#split](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split) and then [String#lstrip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-lstrip).

```
> long = b.p.text
 => "Name: 12121" 

> short = b.p.strong.text
 => "Name:" 

> long.split(short)
 => ["", " 12121"] 

> long.split(short)[1]
 => " 12121" 

> long.split(short)[1].lstrip
 => "12121"
```

Comment: that I have already tried, I was looking for some alternative to do

Comment: You should said it in the question what you have already tried. That would save me some time.

Answer (score 1):

While I think that parsing the paragraph elements text is the easiest, if you really just want to get the text node, you could use javascript.

If you know that the text will always be the last part of the paragraph, you can do:

```
browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].lastChild.nodeValue", browser.p)
#=> "12121"
```

If the structure can change and you want all text of the paragraph element, without the children element's text, you can generalize it:

```
get_text_node_script = <<-SCRIPT
    var nodes = arguments[0].childNodes;
    var result = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if(nodes[i].nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            result += nodes[i].nodeValue; 
        }
    }   
    return result
SCRIPT

browser.execute_script(get_text_node_script, browser.p)
#=> "12121"
```